# I/O failure while processing configuration class

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-17

```
`**org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: I/O failure while processing configuration class \[org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfiguration\]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250) \~\[spring-context-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1\]**`
```

i receive above error when migrate to springboot 3.2.0. got any suggeston solution for above error?

already add a few dependency such as:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

bust still dint work.

Answer (score 1):

I got same error after refactoring class names. It fixed when I simply deleted the 'target' folder and run it again. It may work in your case as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue after I upgraded the spring boot to 3.2, but this issue only occurred when I was using IDEA,(I changed the Java SDK to 17 in IDEA
), The same code running well in STS4.

Comment: Hi Fernando, may i know what is STS 4?

Comment: Spring Tool Suite 4